Trouble adding new entities in symfony / doctrine
I am getting the error "A new entity was found through the relationship 'App\Entity\UserProfileMatch#profile'" with the code below in my Symfony / Doctrine app.
Details:
I have the following Profile entity:
<?php

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ProfileRepository::class)]
#[ORM\Table(name: '`profile`')]
class Profile
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer', unique: true)]
    private ?int $userId = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer', unique: true)]
    private ?int $profileTypeId = null;

    // Relationships
    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: ProfileType::class)]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(name: 'profile_type_id', referencedColumnName: 'id', nullable: false)]
    private ?ProfileType $profileType = null;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity: UserProfileMatch::class, mappedBy: 'profile', cascade: ['persist'])]
    private Collection $userProfileMatch;

    // .. getters and setters
}

?>

And the following UserMatchProfile entity:
<?php

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: UserProfileMatchRepository::class)]
#[ORM\Table(name: '`user_profile_match`')]
class UserProfileMatch
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private ?int $profileId = null;

    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private ?int $profileTypeId = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Profile::class, cascade: ['persist'], inversedBy: 'UserProfileMatch')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private ?Profile $profile = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: ProfileType::class, inversedBy: 'UserProfileMatch')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private ?ProfileType $profileType = null;

    // getts and setters
}
?>

They both have a relationship with ProfileTYpe Entity:
<?php

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ProfileTypeRepository::class)]
#[ORM\Table(name: '`profile_type`')]
class ProfileType
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 50, unique: true)]
    private ?string $option = null;

    public function getId(): ?int

    // getters and setters
}
?>

The above defines the following relationships:
Profile entity has one associated ProfileType entity
Profile may have multiple UserProfileMatch entities associated with it
UserProfileMatch may have one or more associated ProfileTypes
There's no issues so far, I can do the following without issues:
<?php

$profile = new Profile();
$profile->setUserId($user->getId());
$profileType = $this->profileTypeRepository->find($formData['profileTypeId']);
$this->entityManager->persist($profile);
$this->entityManager->flush();
?>

Data is saved as expected.

But then I expand the code by adding the following code immediately after it:

<?php
    $this->userProfileMatchRepository->deleteAllByProfileId($user->getId());
    $this->entityManager->clear();
    $this->entityManager->flush();

    foreach ($formData['match_profile_type_id'] as $profileTypeId) {
        $profileType = $this->profileTypeRepository->find($profileTypeId);
        $userProfileMatch = new UserProfileMatch();
        $userProfileMatch->setProfile($profile);
        $userProfileMatch->setProfileId($profile->getId());
        $userProfileMatch->setProfileType($profileType);
        $userProfileMatch->setProfileTypeId($profileTypeId);
        $this->entityManager->persist($userProfileMatch);
    }
    $this->entityManager->flush();
?>

And I get the following error:

new entity was found through the relationship
'App\Entity\Profile#profileType' that was not configured to cascade
persist operations for entity: App\Entity\ProfileType@539. To solve
this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this
unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the
mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot
find out which entity causes the problem implement
'App\Entity\ProfileType#__toString()' to get a clue.

I only get the above error when trying to save the UserProfileMatch entity.  I don't think setting cascade for the profile_type associated is ideal as the profile_type table should never be updated.
What am I doing wrong here, please help.

Doctrine will only update your profile_type table if the entity is "a new one" then in my opinion setting cascade persist is not an issue because you are getting the profilType entity from your database. Either you set the cascade or you have to persist the entity in your code before persisting $userProfileMatch...

@MoWiz Removing "$this->entityManager->clear();" resolved the issue, i'm not 100% sure why, it was a solution reached by good fortune only on my part

I don't see why either  . If it worked for you it's cool
